# Alternative to NotebookLocate or NotebookFind

Tags: notebooks, version-8, cells

In *Mathematica* 8.0 and older, there are two ways  to select cells based on cell tags.

```
NotebookLocate["CellTag"];
NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

and

```
NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "CellTag", All, CellTags, AutoScroll -> False];
NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

When executing either of these the user selection becomes modified. By manually extracting the cells from the notebook, the user selection is not modified. Therefore, you could run `NotebookGet` in some type of a loop or in another user interface without messing with user's interactions.

Now `NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]]` holds the Notebook data.  So how can I extract cells as if I had run one of the commands above using `NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]]`?

**EDIT:** Here is a working solution http://pastebin.com/mvFPqvVY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pre-V9 solution

My answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30110/cases-message-valid-notebook-structure/30124#30124) turns out to be applicable to this question, too.
There I had written this function that goes traverses a notebook's expression tree down to the level of what I will call the "notebook's cells."  These are the ones displayed with a cell bracket (so it does not find inline cells).

```
cells[nb_NotebookObject] := cells[nb, _];
cells[nb_NotebookObject, pat_] := Flatten @ cells[First @ NotebookGet[nb], pat];
cells[cellList_List, pat_] := cells[#, pat] & /@ cellList;
cells[Cell[CellGroupData[group_List, ___]], pat_] := cells[#, pat] & /@ group;
cells[c_Cell, pat_] := If[MatchQ[c, pat], c, {}];
cells[__] := {};
```

---

It was the OP, [Liam](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5615), actually, who wrapped this function in an interface to search by tag, and kindly invited me to include it in this answer:

```
CellsByTag[notebook_, tag_] := Module[{cells},
  cells[nb_NotebookObject] := cells[nb, _];
  cells[nb_NotebookObject, pat_] := Flatten@cells[First@NotebookGet[nb], pat];
  cells[cellList_List, pat_] := cells[#, pat] & /@ cellList;
  cells[Cell[CellGroupData[group_List, ___]], pat_] := cells[#, pat] & /@ group;
  cells[c_Cell, pat_] := If[MatchQ[c, pat], c, {}];
  cells[__] := {};
  cells[notebook, _?(MemberQ[Flatten[{CellTags} /. Options[#]], tag] &)]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you are looking for?

**V8**

```
Cases[
      NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]],
      Cell[__, CellTags -> "tag", ___]
      , \[Infinity]]
```

**V9**

```
NotebookRead @ First @ Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], CellTags -> "CellTag"]
```

Comment: @Liam does `Cases` works for you?

Comment: Not all `Cell`s will be in level 2 because of `CellGrouping`s.  My next reaction was to have `Cases` select with `Infinity`.  Try running the following in an new notebook. http://pastebin.com/2vaixT2e

Comment: @Liam You are right, this came to my mind but I forgot to check.

Comment: I thought you did ;), but you didn't my use cases so it might have worked.  Further investigation if you run the following code http://pastebin.com/BgDGa3eZ then you try running `NotebookLocate["MyTag"];NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]]` you get 5 elements with `Cases` vs 2 with `NotebookRead`

Comment: @Liam Maybe this pattern is enough `Cell[__, CellTags -> "MyTag"]`? Then I have 2 matching cells, this one with Cases and the one you are looking for. It seems that CellTag is at the end but I'm not sure.

Comment: Trying running this http://pastebin.com/BgDGa3eZ then `Length@Cases[NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]],Cell[__, CellTags -> "MyTag", ___], \[Infinity]]` or `Length@Cases[NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]],Cell[__, CellTags -> "MyTag", ___], \[Infinity]]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10030/discussion-between-liam-and-kuba)

Comment: Surely, you want instead `NotebookRead /@ Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], CellTags -> "CellTag"]`.  By using `First`, you're only getting the first of many cells, or generating an error condition when you try to get the first of zero cells.

Comment: The v8 solution has another problem.  It fails to find cells with multiple cell tags.  E.g., a cell with `CellTags->{"tag", "abc"}`.

Comment: @JohnFultz I agree about `First`, I assumed there is one and only one cell with such tag. This code is so short I thought is will be clear that `First` is for particular case and one have to implement some conditional construct to make it bulletproof. About v.8. you are right again :), I should have put some more effor to make this more general answer, I will try to do this this evening. Thank you for those remarks.