# Cases Message Valid Notebook Structure

Tags: notebooks, warning-messages, message-coding

**Note: Spelunking will likely be needed.**

Execute the following.  You should get back and error along the lines of `First::first:..`.  This error is unimportant except it helps illustrate a potential issue with `Cases` internal code.

```
Print[Button["Print Cell",
   Cell[BoxData[
     ToBoxes@
      First@Cases[NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]][[1]], 
        Cell[___, CellTags -> "MyCode", ___]]
     ], "Input", CellTags -> "MyGraphic"]
   ]
  ];
CellPrint@
  Cell[BoxData[
    ToBoxes[Cases[NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
      Cell[___, CellTags -> "MyGraphic", ___], Infinity], StandardForm]
    ], "Output", CellTags -> "MyCode"];
```

Now ultimately although the notebook is outputting an error the Notebook itself should have a valid structure, considering the notebook can be saved and duplicated like so `NotebookPut@NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]]`.

Interestingly if execute the following code in the same `Notebook`.

```
Cases[NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]]
 , Cell[__, CellTags -> "MyGraphic"], Infinity]
```

`Cases` return the appropriate values and you get back a `First::first` error.

My question: **Why does `Cases` return a message from a perfectly valid `Notebook` structure.  Other then using `Quiet` to suppress an error, how might I solve such a problem?**

Comment: You're not calling `Cases` at the proper level. See the third argument of `Cases`... use level `Infinity`

Comment: @rm-rf I'm sorry not sure what you mean `Infinity` means at calling at every level, yes?

Comment: See the difference between `Cases[{{Cell["foo", CellTags -> "bar"]}}, 
 Cell[__, CellTags -> "bar", ___]]` and `Cases[{Cell["foo", CellTags -> "bar"]}, 
 Cell[__, CellTags -> "bar", ___]]`... by default `Cases` operates at level spec `{1}`, which is why the first returns `{}` whereas the second returns a cell. In a generic notebook expression, the cell tag rule is at an arbitrary depth, which you may or may not know in advance. It certainly isn't at level `{1}`. So you use `Infinity` to tell `Cases` to look for the pattern at all levels.

Comment: @rm-rf but the 2nd `Cases` is set to `Infinity`.  Read the question again.  My question isn't why the 1st error is outputted, but why a perfectly valid `Notebook` structure causes the 2nd `Cases` to return a message in addition to returning the output.  Something internally on how `Cases` is structure is causing the issue.

Comment: @rm-rf In the following example the Notebook structure is somehow causing `Cases` to fail http://pastebin.com/uP7CNrUS

Comment: Ok, my apologies for misinterpreting. In any case, the error your seeing with the second example is because `Cases` evaluates the arguments. Your button is what's causing it to throw an error. While the rest of the notebook is a bunch of inert strings in boxes, the button function is present as an evaluatable expression. When `Cases` encounters it, it evaluates it and this expression is `First@Cases[...]`, which as I explained earlier, should throw an error.

Comment: @rm-rf I had guessed `Cases` was evaluating something ;).  Might you know of a fix the prevents it from evaluating the expressions and therefore allows the code to work properly.

Comment: The "fix" is to use the correct levelspec... As I said, in general you'll not find a cell tag at that level, so this button is designed to generate an error. If you're asking for a version of `Cases` that doesn't evaluate its leaves, that's a bigger task which possibly deserves its own question. I don't know how to write such a version of `Cases` off the top of my head, but you should read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8701756) by Leonid. You might be able to use it to "shield" certain expressions (like `ButtonFunction`'s RHS, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "answer", if it can be considered an answer, consists of a mixture of comments and suggestions.

---

Aside from dealing with levels as [rm-rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5) has shown in another answer, one probably ought to deal with the possibility of `Cases` returning `{}`, even if it should not happen.  How to deal with it is something you should decide.  Here's a way to return `Null`, if it's of any help:

```
First[Cases[..] /. {} -> {Null}]
```

---

You can avoid the `Cell` pattern matching itself if, as I surmise, the "MyCode" and "MyGraphics" tags indicate the type of cells.  Code and graphics cells start `Cell[BoxData[..],..]`.  So the patterns could be these:

```
Cell[_BoxData, ___, CellTags -> "MyCode", ___]
Cell[_BoxData, ___, CellTags -> "MyGraphic", ___]
```

---

You can get the cells in a notebook, except inline cells, at level 1 in a `List`, with the following (not extensively tested, however):

```
Clear[cells];
cells[nb_NotebookObject] := cells[nb, _];
cells[nb_NotebookObject, pat_] := Flatten @ cells[First @ NotebookGet[nb], pat];
cells[cellList_List, pat_] := cells[#, pat] & /@ cellList;
cells[Cell[CellGroupData[group_List, ___]], pat_] := cells[#, pat] & /@ group;
cells[c_Cell, pat_] := If[MatchQ[c, pat], c, {}];
cells[__] := {};
```

All cells:

```
cells[EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

You can even get only the cells matching a pattern:

```
cells[EvaluationNotebook[],
      _?(MemberQ[Flatten[{CellTags} /. Options[#]], "MyCode"] &)]
```

Comment: This question was a follow up from here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30069/alternative-to-notebooklocate-or-notebookfind If you would like you are welcome to post an answer and receive more points (like you really need them)

Comment: Genious technique, you are welcome to the following function as an answer at the above question. http://pastebin.com/mvFPqvVY

Comment: @Liam Thanks for pointing it out.  I've been busy and haven't kept up with all the questions.

Answer (score 4):

The following expression should result in an error:

```
First@Cases[NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]][[1]], Cell[___, CellTags -> "MyCode", ___]]]
```

because `Cases`, by default, operates at level `{1}` and in a notebook's expression, `CellTags` will never be at level `{1}`. Thus, `Cases` returns `{}` and `First` throws an error. The solution here, is to use level `Infinity`.

Now coming to the second `Cases` — you've now evaluated the first code block and you have a button in your notebook. This button's expression is:

```
ButtonBox["\"Print Cell\"", Appearance -> Automatic, 
    ButtonFunction :> Cell[
       BoxData[
           ToBoxes[First[Cases[NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]][[1]], 
               Cell[___, CellTags -> "MyCode", ___]]]
           ]
       ], 
       "Input", CellTags -> "MyGraphic"
   ], Evaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Preemptive"
]
```

Note that this expression is stored as an input expression instead of parsed boxform expression. As `Cases` walks through the tree, it evaluates the leaves and the RHS of `ButtonFunction` gets evaluated, which is what results in the error (for reasons explained above).

Comment: @Liam The "fix" is to use the correct levelspec in the 1st `Cases`... As I said, in general you'll not find a cell tag at that level, so this button is designed to generate an error. So as long as that incorrect button is present, the 2nd `Cases` will throw an error. You should also read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8701756) by Leonid. You might be able to use it to "shield" certain expressions (like `ButtonFunction`'s RHS, for example).